Migrating from AngularJS to Angular proposal. Is this a valid path forward?
I am contracting with a company that has an AngularJS application that they "eventually" want migrated to Angular, but the project I am on will have a lot of brand new development (pages and components) that they want in Angular. They do not have the setup finished to the hybrid app set up.
I had a thought to get up and running and got it going with a PoC to build an Angular 17 library. Any new components and pages could be built here then pretty easily included in the current project with downgradeComponent (got this working). Existing components can be slowly pulled out into the library as time allows. Then I am imagining that when they are ready to fully go to Angular, they can replace the current AngularJS project and if they don't want the library, it should be pretty easy to just move Angular code over to the Angular project. But they could keep the library for any reusable components as well. This also lets us get going quickly as we don't have to mess around with their current build process for building the AngularJS app.
A big push for me to think about doing this is the current folder structure is a bit messy with using AngularJS and Razor... So this would give us the opportunity of getting a much more standard and clean project structure that is pulled out of the existing messy repo.
But I am not the most expert Angular developer and this is my first time working in it professionally and wanted to get some advice on more seasoned Angular devs if the library approach for migrating is valid, or if it will potentially have more problems later and should be avoided.

Also consider the added complexity of introducing a library that will change constantly. This means more merge conflicts and all the joys of managing versions.I would encourage hybrid app with DowngradeComponent as you mentioned, and chunk away at it piece by piece.

There shouldn't be complexity outside of the version of the library changing. It is just lifting components from one place and moving them to another. And merge conflicts will happen to the existing app too. PRs will get created, reviewed, and merged and if something causes a conflict, it has to be resolved by the dev and reviewed again.

Yes, you will get merge conflicts on the main app. But only when two people modify the same file. Every change to the library introduces a merge conflict on the package.json in the main app. It's not a primary concern, just something to consider.

Depending on the versioning. There shouldn't be any changes to package.json in the main app unless a major version update of the library.

While that's true, I believe package-lock.json will still conflict. It will change even if you have ^ version set in package.json. Seems like more of a headache than getting hybrid app setup to me. There are more than one way, this could work for you.

Your case does not have much low level description. A more detailed description would be nice, like your folder structure. Keep in mind that holding two framework versions is no easy task. Some dependecies can break and maybe you have to replace them yourself. That said, we have done something similiar using downgradecomponent, and it works very well. It is a valid path forward.

The problem is there isn't much way around using two framework versions. They gotta get out of AngularJS lol. But do not have the time to take everything down and redo it, so it will be piece by piece. I found the library approach very easy to implement into the existing angularJS project, but having a huge problem trying to build the angularjs and angular project together to one can access the other... The library seems more enticing.
